# Address writing with multiple lines

Tags: author, affiliation

I wrote a tex document with following kind of commands for address.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,hyperref}
\begin{document}
\title{Paper 1}
\author{Rahul}
\address{Indian Institute of Science,\\ 
Bangalore\\
India}
\end{document}
```

However, in the pdf file, the address was coming in single line, although I used new-line commands " \\ " in the address. Why this happens, or how to write address in multiple lines?

Comment: The minimum working example is wrong formatted. Every `\begin{document}` fragment must concluded by `\end{document}` fragment. Update your question.

Comment: Try with `\newline` instead of  double backslashes.

Comment: You can not use line break inside the curly brackets. That confuses. Instead write separate line for each part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the `\address` field is intended to be a single line right shifted text field (possibly comma separated) for use with `\maketitle`.  While `\newline` works, it messes up the right shift.  If you really want a multiline address, I suggest using a \parbox.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,hyperref}
\title{Paper 1}
\author{Rahul}
\address{\parbox{\linewidth}{Indian Institute of Science,\\
Bangalore\\
India}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: \newline produces space-difference; the \parbox{linewidth} works better. Thank you very much for the suggestion.